# Ruby send_file and store it directly to local folder using FileUtils

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri, fileutils

I am currently able to send a docx file for the user to download, question is **how do I save the file created for download from the `send_file` method to store into a local directory in a ruby app?**

Below is the code that uses `send_file`:

```
send_file rand_file, :type => 'docx', :filename => "#{@report.report_name}.docx"
```

Comment: directory local to what, the app or the user?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in the server directory

Comment: Since you have the file already on the server, you "save" it by simply copying (or moving) it to desired location (`FileUtils.cp`).

Comment: Thanks @katafrakt for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solve my problem by using tips from @katafrakt and @rantingsonrails by using the FileUtils method of copying just before the send_file command. Below are my code on how i did it.

```
temp_file_path = "./document/#{@report.report_name}.docx"
FileUtils::copy_file(rand_file,temp_file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the file prior to calling send_file and then reference it as such

```
file = File.open(temp_file_path, 'w+')
file.binmode
file.write(rand_file.read)
file.close
file = Tempfile.new('temp_file_path', 'tmp')
send_file file, ...
```

Comment: thanks for your tips but i go with katafrakt suggestion on using (FileUtils.cp) as the solution to my problem.